# Maven module hierarchy

Tags: java, android, maven, module, pom.xml

I have two modules(maven projects) in parent maven project: android-module and server-module. This two modules uses identical models(POJO - classes). So I want extract models from both modules and make new module in parent project.

So I whant this:

```
--Project
 |--android-module
 |  -- pom.xml
 |--server-module
 |  -- pom.xml
  -- pom.xml
```

remake to this:

```
--Project
 |--android-module
 |  -- pom.xml
 |--server-module
 |  -- pom.xml
 |--models-module
 |  -- pom.xml
  -- pom.xml
```

At the same time I want to root pom.xml compiles and build jar from models-module and store jar in my local repository. Then child pom.xml's were taking it from the repository and included in the android and server modules.

Question: How to tell maven to build and store jar in my local repository automatically.

Is it possible? If no - please, give me some ideas.... Thnks

Comment: Is whether this is possible your whole question?

Comment: Oh, sorry. My question is how to say maven to build and store jar automatically

Comment: Are you just asking for `mvn:install`?

Answer (score 0):

Just run `mvn install`. This will install the packaged jar into your local repo in ~/.m2

Make sure you run maven from the root pom

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found. It was much easier.

parent pom.xml:

```
...
<groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
<artifactId>doiter</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>doiter-android</module>
    <module>doiter-server</module>
    <module>doiter-model</module>
</modules>
...
```

child1 (android project) pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
    <artifactId>doiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
<artifactId>doiter-android</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
        <artifactId>doiter-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

child2 (server) pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
    <artifactId>doiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.doiter.server</groupId>
<artifactId>doiter-server</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
        <artifactId>doiter-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

child3 (shared models) pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
    <artifactId>doiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.lutshe</groupId>
<artifactId>doiter-model</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
```